# Catching an error message with retrofit HttpException

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm using `Retrofit` to make some requests to the API, and when I receive back the response it's usually received from the API in this format if the request is successful

**Successful Response**

```json
{
    "success": 1,
    "error": [],
    "data": [
        // Some data..
     ]
}
```

And if there is an error, the response will go like this

**Unsuccessful Response**

```json
{
    "success": 0,
    "error": [
        "Password is incorrect"
    ],
    "data": []
}
```

The problem now in case there is an unsuccessful request, it comes with `error code 403`, so Retrofit classifies it as an Exception and throws an `HttpException`, then i have no way to catch the `password is incorrect` message attached in the `json` response.

Is there any way I still can get the body response even if there is an HttpException?

#### Update

This is the sample code I'm using

**ViewModel**

```kotlin
viewModelScope.launch {
    try {
        val result = myApi.request(requestParam)
    }catch (e: HttpException){
        // Log the error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I figured out a way to get back the response from the passed exception.

As I said in the question, this is the code I'm using

**Old code sample**

```kotlin
viewModelScope.launch {
    try {
        val result = myApi.request(requestParam)
    }catch (e: HttpException){
        // Log the error
    }
}
```

However, I didn't know that the response body is passed with the exception, and you can receive it as a string using the `errorBody()` method as follows.

**New code sample**

```kotlin
viewModelScope.launch {
    try {
        val result = myApi.request(requestParam)
    }catch (e: HttpException){
        val response = e.response()?.errorBody()?.string()
    }
}
```

And from there you can manipulate this string to extract the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extension method like this:

```
inline fun Job.onHttpError(crossinline block: (HttpException) -> Unit) {
 this. invokeOnCompletion {
     if (it != null && it is HttpException) block(it)
 }
}
```

Then you can get the exception information like this:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
  val result = global.apiService.legalDigitalList()
}.onHttpError {
  showLog(it. message)
}
```